# mysql inner join query running slow

Tags: mysql, inner-join, explain

This is my mysql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.lineid
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tmd.lineid, a.linename
      FROM tagmodeldata tmd
           INNER JOIN
           tagline a
           ON a.documentid = tmd.documentid AND tmd.tagvalue = 3
      WHERE tmd.documentid = 926980) a
      INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT tmd.lineid, b.linename
      FROM tagmodeldata tmd
           INNER JOIN
           tagline b
           ON b.documentid = tmd.documentid AND tmd.tagvalue IN (0 , 1)
      WHERE tmd.documentid = 926980) b
      ON b.linename = a.linename;
```

it is taking ~160s to run which is too slow for me. the basic idea is to retrieve those lineids where linename with tagvalue is 3, matches the linename with tagvalue 0 or 1.

```
+--+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------+
|  | id | select_type |   table    | type |       possible_keys       |      key       | key_len | ref  | rows  |             Extra              |
+--+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------+
|  |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ALL  | NULL                      | NULL           | NULL    | NULL | 14760 | Using temporary                |
|  |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL                      | NULL           | NULL    | NULL | 72160 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  |  3 | DERIVED     | b          | ref  | documentid                | documentid     |       5 |      |   593 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  |  3 | DERIVED     | tmd        | ref  | documentid,document_index | document_index |       4 |      | 66784 | Using where                    |
|  |  2 | DERIVED     | a          | ref  | documentid                | documentid     |       5 |      |   593 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  |  2 | DERIVED     | tmd        | ref  | documentid,document_index | document_index |       4 |      | 66784 | Using where                    |
+--+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Provide sample data for your query.  A SQL Fiddle would help.  You probably can simplify it, but without knowing what the data  looks like, it is really hard to help.

Comment: Better yet, run EXPLAIN PLAN and look for table scans.  You're probably missing an index.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want lines for a particular document that have both 3 and either 0 or 1.  If so, you can just use conditional aggregation.  The resulting query is something like this:

```
SELECT tmd.lineid
FROM tagmodeldata tmd INNER JOIN
     tagline a
     ON a.documentid = tmd.documentid AND tmd.tagvalue IN (0, 1, 3)
WHERE tmd.documentid = 926980
GROUP BY tmd.lineid
HAVING SUM(tmd.tagvalue = 3) > 0 AND
       SUM(tmd.tagvalue IN (0, 1)) > 0;
```

It is unclear what the relationship is between `tagline.linename` and `tagline.lineid`.  The above assumes that they are the same.